# facebook sdk android, com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid application

Tags: android, facebook

My application works in the emulator and recognizes the session, but in the phone gives this error "com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid application 523937644333547"

this is the logcat

```
*05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631): Exception during service
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid application 523937644333547
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:208)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:266)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:27)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:141)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:284)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:185)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:245)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:51)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:191)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at com.facebook.common.executors.HandlerExecutorServiceImpl$ListenableScheduledFuture.run(HandlerExecutorServiceImpl.java:268)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-25 01:06:53.027: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(31631):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
05-25 01:06:53.117: W/kernel(130): [522168.671081] select 31563 (n.customization), adj 8, size 3363, to kill
05-25 01:06:53.117: W/kernel(130): [522168.671112] select 32156 (android.vending), adj 9, size 4828, to kill
05-25 01:06:53.117: W/kernel(130): [522168.671142] send sigkill to 32156 (android.vending), adj 9, size 4828
05-25 01:06:53.477: D/dalvikvm(31631): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1871K, 33% free 8741K/12999K, external 2082K/2133K, paused 4ms+6ms
05-25 01:06:54.027: W/kernel(130): [522169.579986] select 31563 (n.customization), adj 8, size 3361, to kill
05-25 01:06:54.027: W/kernel(130): [522169.580047] select 32215 (d.process.media), adj 9, size 4146, to kill
05-25 01:06:54.027: W/kernel(130): [522169.580108] send sigkill to 32215 (d.process.media), adj 9, size 4146*
```

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: You should post you logcat!